# Code inside try-catch block is throwing exceptions and breaking execution even when written to ignore excetion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

I am working on a VSTO Word Add-in project. I was initially using **Visual Studio Community 2017** version. I then upgraded to the 2019 version and migrated my Word VSTO Add-in project accordingly. Then I started noticing a strange occurrence suddenly while executing codes.

Some codes that have been surrounded with a **try-catch** block so that expected exceptions can be purposely ignored suddenly begins to throw exception and break the code even with the try block in place. This has never happened with the 2017 version. The catch portion of the code that is meant to catch the exception doesn't get executed!

The code is statement that tries to get a returned string from an object after the object calls a particular method. The calling objects can sometimes be inevitably `null` and all that the design will want to do when such is encountered is to ignore and move to the next step which perform actions that depends on whether a string was gotten from the **try-catch** block or not. I need someone to help me explain this please.

The code is as shown below:

```
string style = null;
try
{
    style = ((Style)paragraphs[i].Range.get_Style()).NameLocal;
}
catch (Exception ex) {} 
if(style != null) 
{
    //do something 
}
else
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Would help if you post full stack trace of this exception. But in any case there is no need to catch ahything in your case - just check "calling objects" for null before accessing them.

Comment: What is null, `paragraphs[i]`, `Range` or the returned `Style`? Take a look at the null-propgation operators; using `catch (Exception) {}` is just about always a bad idea

Comment: @Flydog57, OK, I will do that. It is the `Range` object that is null.

Comment: @Evk, OK I understand. But I need to know why this wasn't behaving this way in Visual Studio 2017 but 2019. Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the try catch and use `style = ((Style)paragraphs[i]?.Range?.get_Style())?.NameLocal;`. Then just test `style` for null.

Comment: @Flydog57, okay. Thanks a bunch!